# Is there Selected Tab Changed Event in the standard WPF Tab Control

Tags: wpf, events, tabcontrol

In WPF, is there an event that can be used to determine when a `TabControl`'s selected tab changes?

I have tried using `TabControl.SelectionChanged` but it is getting fired many times when a child's selection within a tab is changed.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

You need to check the event's source to isolate the outer-most `TabControl` you are looking for.

I tied this in the handler to make it work:

```
void TabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Source is TabControl)
    {
        // do work when tab is changed
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought this wasn't working but then I realized I was checking for `sender` instead of `e.Source`

Comment: or just add `e.Handled = true` to prevent it from bubbling up

Comment: @BrockHensley: That could cause you to have to add a whole lot of event handlers that wouldn't otherwise be necessary.

Answer (score 96):

If you set the `x:Name` property to each `TabItem` as:

```
<TabControl x:Name="MyTab" SelectionChanged="TabControl_SelectionChanged">
    <TabItem x:Name="MyTabItem1" Header="One"/>
    <TabItem x:Name="MyTabItem2" Header="2"/>
    <TabItem x:Name="MyTabItem3" Header="Three"/>
</TabControl>
```

Then you can access to each `TabItem` at the event:

```
private void TabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (MyTabItem1.IsSelected)
    // do your stuff
    if (MyTabItem2.IsSelected)
    // do your stuff
    if (MyTabItem3.IsSelected)
    // do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 62):

If you just want to have an event when a tab is selected, this is the correct way:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Selector.Selected="OnTabSelected" />
    <TabItem Selector.Selected="OnTabSelected" />
    <TabItem Selector.Selected="OnTabSelected" />
    <!-- You can also catch the unselected event -->
    <TabItem Selector.Unselected="OnTabUnSelected" />
</TabControl>
```

And in your code

```
    private void OnTabSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var tab = sender as TabItem;
        if (tab != null)
        {
            // this tab is selected!
        }
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately as nice as this one looks, I don't get the Selected property available to me in xaml, just the IsSelected.  Sorry.

Comment: I stand corrected....kind of.  DOH!  When I try to type about the above in VS, it gives me the red squigglies, hence I thought it was wrong. BUT when I cut'n'pasted it in and just blindly F5'd it, to my astonishment, IT WORKED.  HUH?!  Why did it work THAT way?

Comment: How can I access "Selector.Selected" event in code instead of xaml

Comment: @Ahmed_Faraz: `someTabItem.AddHandler(Selector.SelectedEvent, ....`

Answer (score 15):

You could still use that event. Just check that the sender argument is the control you actually care about and if so, run the event code.

Answer (score 7):

If you're using the MVVM pattern then it is inconvenient (and breaks the pattern) to use the event handler. Instead, you can bind each individual TabItem's `Selector.IsSelected` property to a dependency property in your viewmodel and then handle the `PropertyChanged` event handler. That way you know exactly which tab was selected/deselected based on the `PropertyName` and you have a special handler for each tab.

Example: `MainView.xaml`

```
<TabControl>
 <TabItem Header="My tab 1" Selector.IsSelected="{Binding IsMyTab1Selected}"> ... </TabItem>
 <TabItem Header="My tab 2" Selector.IsSelected="{Binding IsMyTab2Selected}"> ... </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Example: `MainViewModel.cs`

```
public bool IsMyTab1Selected {
 get { return (bool)GetValue(IsMyTab1SelectedProperty); }
 set { SetValue(IsMyTab1SelectedProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsMyTab1SelectedProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register("IsMyTab1Selected", typeof(bool), typeof(MainViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(true, new PropertyChangedCallback(MyPropertyChanged)));

public bool IsMyTab2Selected {
 get { return (bool)GetValue(IsMyTab2SelectedProperty); }
 set { SetValue(IsMyTab2SelectedProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsMyTab2SelectedProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register("IsMyTab2Selected", typeof(bool), typeof(MainViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(MyPropertyChanged)));

private void MyPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
 if (e.Property.Name == "IsMyTab1Selected") {
  // stuff to do
 } else if (e.Property.Name == "IsMyTab2Selected") {
  // stuff to do
 }
}
```

If your `MainViewModel` is `INotifyPropertyChanged` rather than `DependencyObject`, then use this instead:

Example: `MainViewModel.cs`

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
 PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

public MainViewModel() {
 PropertyChanged += handlePropertyChanged;
}

public bool IsMyTab1Selected {
 get { return _IsMyTab1Selected ; }
 set {
  if (value != _IsMyTab1Selected ) {
   _IsMyTab1Selected = value;
   OnPropertyChanged("IsMyTab1Selected ");
  }
 }
}
private bool _IsMyTab1Selected = false;

public bool IsMyTab2Selected {
 get { return _IsMyTab2Selected ; }
 set {
  if (value != _IsMyTab2Selected ) {
   _IsMyTab2Selected = value;
   OnPropertyChanged("IsMyTab2Selected ");
  }
 }
}
private bool _IsMyTab2Selected = false;

private void handlePropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
 if (e.PropertyName == "IsMyTab1Selected") {
  // stuff to do
 } else if (e.PropertyName == "IsMyTab2Selected") {
  // stuff to do
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

That is the correct event.  Maybe it's not wired up correctly?

```
<TabControl SelectionChanged="TabControl_SelectionChanged">
    <TabItem Header="One"/>
    <TabItem Header="2"/>
    <TabItem Header="Three"/>
</TabControl>
```

in the codebehind....

```
private void TabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    int i = 34;
}
```

if I set a breakpoint on the i = 34 line, it ONLY breaks when i change tabs, even when the tabs have child elements and one of them is selected.

Comment: put a grid in the tab, selecting a grid row will bubble up to the tab selected event if not handled before it gets there.

Answer (score 4):

The event generated is bubbling up until it is handled.

This xaml portion below triggers `ui_Tab_Changed` after `ui_A_Changed` when the item selected in the `ListView` changes, regardless of `TabItem` change in the `TabControl`.

```
<TabControl SelectionChanged="ui_Tab_Changed">
  <TabItem>
    <ListView SelectionChanged="ui_A_Changed" />
  </TabItem>
  <TabItem>
    <ListView SelectionChanged="ui_B_Changed" />
  </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

We need to consume the event in `ui_A_Changed` (and `ui_B_Changed`, and so on):

```
private void ui_A_Changed(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
  // do what you need to do
  ...
  // then consume the event
  e.Handled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This code seems to work:

```
    private void TabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TabItem selectedTab = e.AddedItems[0] as TabItem;  // Gets selected tab

        if (selectedTab.Name == "Tab1")
        {
            // Do work Tab1
        }
        else if (selectedTab.Name == "Tab2")
        {
            // Do work Tab2
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing mvvm, you can also do this by binding to the SelectedIndex Property of TabControl:

```
<TabControl SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedTabIndex}"
```

Then you get notified of the change when the Property updates, and you immediately get the index of the selected TabItem.

Answer (score -2):

If anyone use WPF Modern UI,they cant use OnTabSelected event.but they can use SelectedSourceChanged event.

like this

```
<mui:ModernTab Layout="Tab" SelectedSourceChanged="ModernTab_SelectedSourceChanged" Background="Blue" AllowDrop="True" Name="tabcontroller" >
```

C# code is

```
private void ModernTab_SelectedSourceChanged(object sender, SourceEventArgs e)
    {
          var links = ((ModernTab)sender).Links;

          var link = this.tabcontroller.Links.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Source == e.Source);

          if (link != null) {
              var index = this.tabcontroller.Links.IndexOf(link);
              MessageBox.Show(index.ToString());
          }            
    }
```

Comment: Using third party arguments are never a solution and should be highly discouraged.

Comment: @steven I wrote this for WPF MUI and this is not answer to question too.but this could be answer wpf mui user.That is why I put this as a answer.
thank you