# Silverlight tabchanged event - tabcontrol

Tags: c#, silverlight, tabs, tabcontrol

I'm using tab control and I want to handle tabchanged event.

I was trying to use `SelectionChanged` event with no luck. It's being fired too many times (after loading tabcontrol, or adding new tab).
I would like to handle this event only when user navigates between tabs.

I have found solution for WPF ([Is there Selected Tab Changed Event in the standard WPF Tab Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772841/is-there-selected-tab-changed-event-in-the-standard-wpf-tab-control)) but it's no good for Silverlight.
TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firing "too many times" should not be a problem if you check for an actual change to the `SelectedIndex` property in the event.

```
private int LastSelectedTab = -1;

void tab_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TabControl tab = sender as TabControl;
    if (this.LastSelectedTab != tab.SelectedIndex)
    {
        this.LastSelectedTab = tab.SelectedIndex;
        // Now do your thing...
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want a generic fix subclass TabControl and implement your own event that only gets called by the above code in that class... `SelectionActuallyChangedByAHuman`? :)