# How to notify the TabItem switching in c#? (if there are many TabItems)

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-5.0, tabitem

I have created TabItems in `silverlight` where each tab display some text. 
When i change the text then it show asterisk at the Header of TabItem with header name.

Now what i want to achieve is :
suppose i made a change on the current TabItem text display then when i switch from the one tab to another tab item then it must show a pop up saying "do you wanna save the
changes done ?"

**Does silverlight provide any facility in TabItem to notify when there is change in the TabItem (I mean when switching is done from one tabitem to another) ?**

On switching here from one tab item to another must pop up a message that do you wanna save the change in the previous tab. **How to get notification of switching the TabItem(NOT TabControl) ?**

Comment: Not sure if I should mark this as duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359765/silverlight-tabchanged-event-tabcontrol) or not.

Comment: Yep, pretty much a duplicate. Use the SelectionChanged event and then set the SelectedItem/Index (or not) based on whether you want to allow the selected tab to change.

Comment: @Mashton SelectionChanhged event do not work for TabItem in Silverlight. any otherway you know ? and its not same as that link

Comment: SelectionChanged is for the TabControl (parent), which is where you should be making the decision of whether to change tabs or not.

Comment: I am changing TabItems (not TabControls). I mean switching of TabItems must popup some messagebox

Comment: When you are switching between TabItems the TabControl will raise a SelectionChanged event.