# How to set focus of a textblock Out of Browser?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-5.0, setfocus

I am working in **silverlight** and i am not able to set focus of textblock whereas i found the way to do for textbox (using `Focus()`) but not textblock.

Could some one please let me help in setting the focus of text block below (Silverlight 5)? :

```
TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
```

Comment: `TextBlock` is no `Control`, therefore it cannot have focus. What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: @Martin see teh question . what i wam tryint to accomplish : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24868119/how-to-notify-the-tabitem-switching-in-c-if-there-are-many-tabitems?noredirect=1#comment38658019_24868119  WHERE PEOPLE MARK IT DUplicate(without even reading it)

Comment: Your other question actually is a duplicate, you can easily use the [SelectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabcontrol.selectionchanged%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) event. The `TabControl` offers it and you can check for pending user changes and prompt the user from within the event handler whenever the user switches tabs. BTW: why do you create a new account every other week?

Answer (score 1):

if its a out of browser application,

```
    if (App.current.IsRunningOutOfBrowser)
    {
        tb.Focus();
    }
    else
    {
        System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Plugin.Focus();
        tb.Focus();
    }
```

Comment: But  ia m not running on browser my silverligth application and it do not recognize .Plugin.Focus();

Comment: This works "using System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage;" but this not : "System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Plugin.Focus();"

Comment: I added " System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Plugin.Focus();
            TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
            tb.Focus();"   atthe top of progaram i included :"using System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage;" BUT "tb.Focus();" gives error this Focus is not recognized.

Comment: No.. Focus() is not working. tb do not contain any definition of Focus(). But this is not Webbrowser wpplication of Silverlight. I have my output on a window (not on browser). Is it due to that ?

Comment: @user3735822  check modified answer

Comment: No it do not work. In the secnd part it do not recogize Dispatcher and Focus both.

Comment: warning :The bridge DOM / scripting is disabled  (corresponding to: System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Plugin.Focus();) BUT I IF CONDITION IS " if(Application.Current.IsRunningOutOfBrowser)" because i am running out of browser.

Comment: Did you found any way to do so ?

Comment: @user3735822 Check modified answer, this how you generally do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57755/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-user3735822).