# SelectionChanged event for TabItems

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I am in a situation where i try to create notification when i try to switch from one TabItem to another and i try to do so using LostFocus().

Actually my each TabItem consists of TextBlock and some data written on it. So the switching notification i try to achieve like this:

```
    StackPanel sp = new StackPanel() 
    { 
       Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal
    };
    sp.Children.Add(generateTextBlockContaini()); 
    TabItem tbi = new TabItem();
    tbi.Header = sp;
    tbi.LostFocus +=(o,e) =>
     {

         //MesssagePop up 
         MessageBox.Show("Hurrey tabItem changed");
     };
```

The problem arises are:

(1) It works fine but i need to click once on the textblock when i switch to another TabItem in order to popup this messagebox (because its focus is not set if i do not click). Is there any way to set focus of textblock in silverlight 5 ?

(2) Even if it is set it will call infinitely because i replaced textblock by textbox and i used Focus() and it was calling infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

Usually TabItems are used together with TabControls.
This provides properties and events for changing tabs.

[Silverlight tabchanged event - tabcontrol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359765/silverlight-tabchanged-event-tabcontrol)

Answer (score 0):

For your particular case you could use `MouseLeave` and `MouseEnter` events instead of `LostFocus` and `GotFocus`. Those events will fire without requiring the user to click on a control inside your `TabItem`.