# WPF TabControl - Check which Tab is active

Tags: c#, wpf

I have got a tab controller with few tabs.
Each tab contains List view and loads data from the database when the tab is visible.

How do get which Tab is selected?

I tried GotFocuse but every click inside the tabs load the data again.
Mouse down kind of works but i need to click twice. First one selectes the tab and the second one loads the data. So it is not practical, didn't work.

I need something like IsSelected event for this tabs.

Comment: Pretty sure it is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772841/is-there-selected-tab-changed-event-in-the-standard-wpf-tab-control

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there Selected Tab Changed Event in the standard WPF Tab Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772841/is-there-selected-tab-changed-event-in-the-standard-wpf-tab-control)