# TabControl Command binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, tabcontrol, tabitem

I am using this code following code taken from Stackoverflow.

I want to transfer a string from one view model to another one on `SelectionChanged` event. But when I click on Tab2, I get Tab2 message box, but when I click on Tab1, I get both the message boxes indicating that both are getting executed. The same when I click Tab1, both message boxes are seen.

**MainView.xaml**

```
<TabControl>
 <TabItem Header="My tab 1" Selector.IsSelected="{Binding IsMyTab1Selected}"> ... </TabItem>
 <TabItem Header="My tab 2" Selector.IsSelected="{Binding IsMyTab2Selected}"> ... </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
 PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

public MainViewModel() {
 PropertyChanged += handlePropertyChanged;
}

public bool IsMyTab1Selected {
 get { return _IsMyTab1Selected ; }
 set {
  if (value != _IsMyTab1Selected ) {
   _IsMyTab1Selected = value;
   OnPropertyChanged("IsMyTab1Selected ");
  }
 }
}
private bool _IsMyTab1Selected = false;

public bool IsMyTab2Selected {
 get { return _IsMyTab2Selected ; }
 set {
  if (value != _IsMyTab2Selected ) {
   _IsMyTab2Selected = value;
   OnPropertyChanged("IsMyTab2Selected ");
  }
 }
}
private bool _IsMyTab2Selected = false;

private void handlePropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
 if (e.PropertyName == "IsMyTab1Selected") {
   MessageBox.Show("Tab_1 Clicked!");
 } else if (e.PropertyName == "IsMyTab2Selected") {
   MessageBox.Show("Tab_2 Clicked!");
 }
}
```

I am not able to get the mutually exclusiveness, point me where I am wrong.

Comment: you can not expect people to go through a multiple pages long link. add a minimal code example in your question. otherwise it is hard to help you. And why is there commented out code?

Comment: @Blechdose got it, so I posted the code taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46074186

Comment: @highlander141: When the first tab's `IsSelected` property is set to true, the second one's is set to false and vice versa. This is the expected behaviour, isn't it? Or what is your issue?

Comment: yes even I thought the same. But both the message boxes are getting executed.
As Gaz has said in his answer, 'e.NewValue' also has to be checked..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1

you can change the setters to only call `OnPropertyChanged(..)` when the value is true:

```
public bool IsMyTab1Selected
{
    get { return _IsMyTab1Selected; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _IsMyTab1Selected)
        {
            _IsMyTab1Selected = value;
            if (_IsMyTab1Selected)
                OnPropertyChanged("IsMyTab1Selected");
        }
    }
}

public bool IsMyTab2Selected
{
    get { return _IsMyTab2Selected; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _IsMyTab2Selected)
        {
            _IsMyTab2Selected = value;
            if(_IsMyTab2Selected)
                OnPropertyChanged("IsMyTab2Selected");
        }
    }
}
```

### Option 2

Or you can check in your `handlePropertyChange()` if the value is true like this

```
private void handlePropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "IsMyTab1Selected")
    {
        if(IsMyTab1Selected)
            MessageBox.Show("Tab_1 Clicked!");
    }
    else if (e.PropertyName == "IsMyTab2Selected")
    {
        if(IsMyTab2Selected)
            MessageBox.Show("Tab_2 Clicked!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The bindings will update on **deselection** too. You need to check `e.NewValue` in your handler, or why not simply check `_IsMyTab1Selected` etc?

Comment: I wanted to communicate from this ViewModel to another using RelayCommand, so I cannot check in xaml.cs code..